# Dictionary as query string parameter in SignalR Android Client

Tags: android, signalr

C# Code

```
var querystringData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
querystringData.Add("UserName", LocalSettings.UserName);
querystringData.Add("LoginId", LocalSettings.LoginId);
hubConnection = new HubConnection("http://...", querystringData);
```

How do I pass the Dictionary as queryString in Android

```
Platform.loadPlatformComponent( new AndroidPlatformComponent() );
String host = "http://....;
String qs = "";
```

//Instead of String I want to pass List/Dictionary

```
HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(host, qs, true, new ConsoleLogger());
HubProxy hub = connection.createHubProxy("calculatorHub");
```

Referring http://whathecode.wordpress.com/2014/03/20/getting-started-with-the-java-signalr-sdk/ as the base

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C# client basically turns the dictionary you pass to "&{key}={value}" for each KeyValuePair. So you should be able to do the same on your side and pass to the `HubConnection` ctor as queryString.

Comment: Small correction instead of "&{key}={value}", "&key=value" is working for me

Comment: I used curly brackets to denote variables

Answer (score 1):

Here my code, works perfect

```
String server = URL + "signalr";
        String CONNECTION_QUERYSTRING ="Bearer=" + BaseActivity.getToken(activity).getAccess_token();
        HubConnection connection = new HubConnection(server, CONNECTION_QUERYSTRING, false, new Logger() {
            @Override
            public void log(String message, LogLevel level) {
                System.out.println(message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Thanks this is great answer. It show you how you can use access token with other parameters needed for Authorize attribute on server side.